# Integrate TortoiseSVN with Jetbrains Youtrack

Tags: svn, issue-tracking, youtrack

Is it possible to integrate TortoiseSVN with Jetbrains Youtrack? Who succeeded and how?

I came across [this](http://blog.lieberlieber.com/2011/01/21/integration-tortoise-svn-and-jetbrains-youtrack/) site, but I still haven't succeeded in setting properties in SVN (no luck getting SVN working from command line to [set properties](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.props.manip)...).

Comment: You know it's possible and I guess you couldn't care less about whoever got it working. I suspect your real question is "I don't know how to do this specific step" or "I do X and expect Y but get Z". Can you please rephrase the question in such terms? Otherwise we know beforehand that the obvious answer (a dump of the blog info) is not valid and don't have any clue about why.

Comment: If you still haven't fixed YurtleTrack, take a look at http://www.asitrack.com. It's a desktop issue tracker with built-in Subversion integration (no plugin required).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You done **Integration** (two steps and two ways operation) in bad way (blog post is just terribly incomplete)

- [Integration with Bug Tracking Systems / Issue Trackers](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-bugtracker.html) chapter can help you to identify, will plugin help you
- [Issue tracker plugins](http://tortoisesvn.net/issuetrackerplugins.html) page contain list for all known bugtrack-plugins for TSVN, and [YurtleTrack](https://github.com/scottiemc7/YurtleTrack) referenced (you can get and install it)
- [Getting Information from the Issue Tracker](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-bugtracker.html#tsvn-dug-bugtracker-ref) and [Issue Tracker Integration](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-hooks-issuetracker) from TortoiseSVN's Settings page will help to configure plugin for usage in some Working Copy

**PS** - setting properties in CLI way is not needed at all: TortoiseSVN have good (GUI) editor for this task

Comment: The article just explains how to get a text box for bug ID and a link to an external URL. That doesn't require any plug-in. The issue tracker integration you mention is another feature (fetching tickets from the tracker).

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario - yes, but 1) did you read my point 1? 2) OP want "**Integrate** TortoiseSVN with Jetbrains Youtrack", not just funny texts in logs

Comment: Not sure if your point 1 is the "you done all bad / blog misinformation" line or the broken link but an article is not misinformation just because you need to so something different.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario - OK, I change wording to more soft form. My point one is "... chapter can help you to identify, will plugin help you"

Comment: Of course, it's an excellent answer and I never meant otherwise :)

Comment: Thx a million for the help, unfortunately YurtleTrack is not working (gives an error "unable to create issue tracker" when I select it from TurtoiseSVN > Settings > Select issue tracker. Thx for the effort though.